# How to make use of the previous plain value of a cell as an argument for \verb and a macro name in the next columns?

Tags: tables, verbatim

I have explored the source codes of `siunitx` manual. It is too complicated for a newbie.
My objective is to avoid repeating, `ampere` for example, in each column of the following table. I just want to type a single `ampere` for the first row, `candela` in the second row, etc in the `tabular` or `longtable` body and I  get the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,array}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt

\ifPreview \let\longtable\tabular \let\endlongtable\endtabular \fi 
\PreviewEnvironment{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{*3{m{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth/3\relax}}}
        \toprule
        Unit & Macro & Symbol\\
        \midrule
        ampere & \verb|\ampere| & \si{\ampere}\\
        candela & \verb|\candela|& \si{\candela}\\
        kelvin & \verb|\kelvin|& \si{\kelvin}\\
        kilogram & \verb|\kilogram|& \si{\kilogram}\\
        meter & \verb|\meter|& \si{\meter}\\
        mole & \verb|\mole|& \si{\mole}\\
        second & \verb|\second|& \si{\second}\\
        \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

How to make use of the previous plain value of a cell as an argument for `\verb` and a macro name in the next columns?

Comment: Solution 1: Use `\DefineShortVerb` from the [`fancyvrb` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) (saves typing). Solution 2: Use an editor that 2a) aligns tabular material at the `&` and 2b) provides block editing. Solution 3. Combine David Carlisle’s answer with the [`collcell` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/collcell).

Comment: Comment on your implicit criticism of David Carlisle's solution as not simple: excluding `longtable` stuff the content is simply that `\csname#1\endcsname` turns a name into a macro, and `\expandafter\string\csname#1\endcsname` turns it into a textual representation of the control sequence.  With `\csname` and `\string` being defined precisely for these purposes, that's as simple as it gets.  Note that you don't really need `\verb` to format the macro, since its two functions, to prevent expansion and change the font, are separately taken care of by `\string` and `\texttt`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,array}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt

\ifPreview \let\longtable\tabular \let\endlongtable\endtabular \fi 
\PreviewEnvironment{longtable}

 \def\z#1{#1&\texttt{\expandafter\string\csname#1\endcsname}&\expandafter\si\csname#1\endcsname\\}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{*3{m{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth/3\relax}}}
        \toprule
        Unit & Macro & Symbol\\
        \midrule
        \z{ampere}
        \z{candela}
        \z{kelvin}
        \z{kilogram}
        \z{meter}
        \z{mole}
        \z{second}
        \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But I noticed that `\verb|\test|` is not exactly the same as `\texttt{\textbackslash test}`.

Comment: Sorry it would work in T1 encoding but not in the default OT1, I changed it to use `\string`

Answer (score 5):

## `fancyvrb`

#### Advantages

- Absolute real verbatim.
- Saves the typing of `\verb`.

#### Disadvantages

- Not fully automatic.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,fancyvrb}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt
\ifPreview \let\longtable\tabular \let\endlongtable\endtabular \fi 
\PreviewEnvironment{longtable}

\DefineShortVerb{\|}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{lls}
    \toprule
    Unit     & Macro       & Symbol    \\ \midrule
    ampere   & |\ampere|   & \ampere   \\
    candela  & |\candela|  & \candela  \\
    kelvin   & |\kelvin|   & \kelvin   \\
    kilogram & |\kilogram| & \kilogram \\
    meter    & |\meter|    & \meter    \\
    mole     & |\mole|     & \mole     \\
    second   & |\second|   & \second   \\ \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

### Output

*(See next output.)*

## `collcell` & [`\string`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66244/16595) <sub>(+ `s` column)</sub>

#### Advantages

- You can write `\<macro>` without a problem.
- Does not need `T1`/`lmodern` (but that would not hurt either).
- You can hide the first line with `\multicolumn`.

#### Disadvantages

- Not real verbatim.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,collcell}

\newcommand*{\myString}[1]{\texttt{\string#1}}
\newcolumntype{v}{>{\collectcell\myString}l<{\endcollectcell}}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt
\ifPreview \let\longtable\tabular \let\endlongtable\endtabular \fi 
\PreviewEnvironment{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{lvs}
    \toprule
    Unit     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Macro} & Symbol    \\ \midrule
    ampere   & \ampere                   & \ampere   \\
    candela  & \candela                  & \candela  \\
    kelvin   & \kelvin                   & \kelvin   \\
    kilogram & \kilogram                 & \kilogram \\
    meter    & \meter                    & \meter    \\
    mole     & \mole                     & \mole     \\
    second   & \second                   & \second   \\ \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## `\detokenize`

#### Advantage

- You can write `\<macro>` without a problem.
- Nearly full verbatim

  - More than one macro allowed
  - `\\`, `%` and `&` are not allowed, braces must match

#### Disadvantages

- The first line gets de-tokenized.
- You cannot use any macros in the first line.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,collcell}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcounter{rowcounter}
\newcolumntype{v}{>{\ifnum\value{rowcounter}>0\relax\ttfamily\fi\collectcell\detokenize}l<{\endcollectcell\stepcounter{rowcounter}}}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt
\ifPreview \let\longtable\tabular \let\endlongtable\endtabular \fi 
\PreviewEnvironment{longtable}

\expandafter\def\expandafter\tabular\expandafter{\tabular\setcounter{rowcounter}{0}}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{lvl}
    \toprule
    Unit     & Macro     & Symbol         \\ \midrule
    ampere   & \ampere   & \si{\ampere}   \\
    candela  & \candela  & \si{\candela}  \\
    kelvin   & \kelvin   & \si{\kelvin}   \\
    kilogram & \kilogram & \si{\kilogram} \\
    meter    & \meter    & \si{\meter}    \\
    mole     & \mole     & \si{\mole}     \\
    second   & \second   & \si{\second}   \\ \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Please reduce the number of keystrokes and apply the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle. :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is essentially what David's answer does but maybe somewhat more convenient as you just store your units in an array-like structure and the rest is created on the fly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,siunitx,booktabs}
\pgfplotstableread{
Unit
ampere
candela
kelvin 
kilogram 
meter
mole
second
}\myunitlist

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableset{
create on use/Macro/.style={create col/copy={Unit}},
create on use/Symbol/.style={create col/copy={Unit}}
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
column type=l,
columns={Unit,Macro,Symbol},
columns/Macro/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content/.add={\ttfamily\expandafter\string\csname}{\endcsname}}},
columns/Symbol/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content/.add={\expandafter\si\csname}{\endcsname}}},
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
]{\myunitlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]